# __int64 to CString returns wrong values - C++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, printf, c-strings, int64

I want to convert a __int64 variable into a CString. The code is exactly this

```
__int64 i64TotalGB;
CString totalSpace;
i64TotalGB = 150;
printf("disk space: %I64d GB\n", i64TotalGB);
totalSpace.Format(_T("%I64d", i64TotalGB));
printf("totalSpace contains: %s", totalSpace);
```

the first printf prints

```
"disk space: 150GB"
```

which it's correct, but the second printf prints randomly high numbers like
 
    `"totalSpace contains: 298070026817519929"`

I also tried to use a INT64 variable instead of a __int64 variable, but the result is the same. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: General advice: Stop pretending, that you were targeting Win9x. You aren't. Use `CStringW` in place of `CString`, replace `_T` and similar macros with an `L` prefix, and live a happy life ever after. In other words: `CStringW totalSpace; totalSpace.Format(L"%I64d", i64TotalGB); wprintf(L"totalSpace contains: %s", totalSpace.GetString());`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here:

```
totalSpace.Format(_T("%I64d", i64TotalGB));
```

you're passing `i64TotalGB` as an argument to the [`_T()` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/data-type-mappings?view=vs-2017) instead of passing it as the second argument to `Format()`.

Try this:

```
totalSpace.Format(_T("%I64d"), i64TotalGB);
```

Having said that, thanks to MS's mess (ha) around character encodings, using `_T` here is not the right thing, as `CString` is composed of a `TCHAR` and not `_TCHAR`. So taking that into account, might as well use `TEXT()` instead of `T()`, as it is dependent on `UNICODE` and not `_UNICODE`:

```
totalSpace.Format(TEXT("%I64d"), i64TotalGB);
```

In addition, this line is wrong as it tries to pass an ATL `CString` as a `char*` (a.k.a. *C-style string*):

```
printf("totalSpace contains: %s", totalSpace);
```

For which the compiler gives this warning:

```
warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'ATL::CString'
```

While the structure of `CString` is practically compatible with passing it like you have, this is still formally *undefined behavior*. Use `CString::GetString()` to safeguard against it:

```
printf("totalSpace contains: %ls", totalSpace.GetString());
```

Note the `%ls` as under my configuration `totalSpace.GetString()` returned a `const wchar_t*`. However, as ["*`printf` does not currently support output into a UNICODE stream.*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l#remarks), the correct version for this line, that will support characters outside your current [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page), is a call to `wprintf()` in the following manner:

```
wprintf("totalSpace contains: %s", totalSpace.GetString());
```

---

Having said ALL that, here's a general advice, regardless of the direct problem behind the question. The far better practice nowadays is slightly different altogether, and I quote from the respectable answer by @IInspectable, saying that *"generic-text mappings were relevant 2 decades ago"*.

What's the alternative? In the absence of good enough reason, try sticking explicitly to `CStringW` (*[A Unicode character type string with CRT support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2017#remarks)*). Prefer the [`L` *character literal*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2017) over the archaic [data/text mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/data-type-mappings?view=vs-2017) that *depend on whether the constant `_UNICODE` or `_MBCS` has been defined in your program*. Conversely, the better practice would be using the wide-character versions of all API and language library calls, such as [`wprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf) instead of `printf()`.

Comment: @IInspectable I am now seeing it [in the docs:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx#Remarks) *"printf does not currently support output into a UNICODE stream."* -- made an edit to reflect. quite a detail but important enough to note IMHO

Answer (score 6):

The bug is a result of numerous issues with the code, specifically these 2:

- `totalSpace.Format(_T("%I64d", i64TotalGB));`

  This uses the [`_T` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/data-type-mappings) in a way it's not meant to be used. It should wrap a single character string literal. In the code it wraps a second argument.
- `printf("totalSpace contains: %s", totalSpace);`

  This assumes an ANSI-encoded character string, but passes a `CString` object, that can store both ANSI as well as Unicode encoded strings.

The recommended course of action is to drop [generic-text mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/generic-text-mappings) altogether, in favor of using Unicode (that's UTF-16LE on Windows) throughout<sup>1</sup>. The generic-text mappings were relevant 2 decades ago, to ease porting of Win9x code to the Windows NT based products.

To do this

- Choose `CStringW` over `CString`.
- Drop all occurences of `_T`, `TEXT`, and `_TEXT`, and replace them with an `L` prefix.
- Use the wide-character version of the Windows API, CRT, and C++ Standard Library.

The fixed code looks like this:

```
__int64 i64TotalGB;
CStringW totalSpace;  // Use wide-character string
i64TotalGB = 150;
printf("disk space: %I64d GB\n", i64TotalGB);
totalSpace.Format(L"%I64d", i64TotalGB);  // Use wide-character string literal
wprintf(L"totalSpace contains: %s", totalSpace.GetString());  // Use wide-character library
```

---

On an unrelated note, while it is technically safe to pass a `CString` object in place of a character pointer in a variable argument list, this is an implementation detail, and not formally documented to work. Call [CString::GetString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring) if you care about correct code.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Unless there is a justifiable reason to use a character encoding that uses `char` as its underlying type (like UTF-8 or ANSI). In that case you should still be explicit about it by using `CStringA`.*

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
totalSpace.Format(_T("%I64d"), i64TotalGB);
```